# How to manage review schema/snippet for google reviews

Tags: schema, review, google-rich-snippets, google-reviews

Can we add the review schema/snippet for google reviews for a organization that has different locations and they have separate google reviews. Each location has different name and on the website we have different pages for those locations and on those pages google review code has been embedded. Now we need to add the review schema for that. We have added the below code

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "https://schema.org/",
    "@type": "LocalBusiness",
    "name": "Location name",
    "image": "https://business.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/image.jpg",
    "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "4.7",
        "reviewCount": "60"
    },
    "review": [
        {
            "@type": "Review",
            "author": "Reviewer name",
            "datePublished": "2022-11-10",
            "description": "Review description",
            "name": "",
            "reviewRating": {
                "@type": "Rating",
                "bestRating": "5",
                "ratingValue": "5",
                "worstRating": "1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But looks like this is not correct when tested. Can anyone advise the correct way to manage the review schema for google reviews.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your author markup should be more verbose and indicate it is a person. This example from Google shows how:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/review-snippet#embedded-review-example

And you could add more details to the business like address, telephone and priceRange. Another example:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/local-business#simple-business-listing

These sound like a website containing reviews about its own local businesses (self-serving), which means they will not be eligible for review stars in the search results:

https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2019/09/making-review-rich-results-more-helpful#updated